# How can I create a 301 redirect to remote domain without question marks (?) and other unimportant text in the request?

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting, cross-domain

I am wanting to start from `http://fubar.com/subpage.php?pageId=99`
And end on another domain `http://newdomain.org/fubar/99`

Here's what I have at the top of my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /subpage.php\?pageId=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^ http://newdomain.org/fubar/?%2 [R=301,L,NE]
```

This is what I am getting.

```
from
http://fubar.com/subpage.php?pageId=99
to
http://newdomain.org/fubar/?pageId=99
```

I do not understand the `?` at the end of the RewriteRule in `?%2`. I hoped to remove it but ended up with just `http://newdomain.org/fubar/`

Bonus question, how can things be reset after testing something like this? I keep having to switch browsers and incognito modes when I break things.

Comment: _“Bonus question, how can things be reset after testing something like this? I keep having to switch browsers and incognito modes when I break things.”_ - use status code `302` instead of `301` while you are testing.

Comment: Thanks. Saw this when you posted it and that was the trick. Circling back around to catch up on comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`THE_REQUEST` variable represents original request received by Apache from your browser and it doesn't get overwritten after execution of other rewrite directives. Example value of this variable is `GET /index.php?id=123 HTTP/1.1`. That means your regex to capture query parameter `pageId` is not correct besides `%2` will always be empty since you are capturing only one value.

You may use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /subpage\.php\?pageId=([^&\s]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://newdomain.org/fubar/%1? [R=301,L,NE]
```

`?` in the end will strip off previous query string which gets forwarded automatically to new URL.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks for the speedy answer and sorry for the delayed response. I worked on it 'till i knew I couldn't figure it out (or figure out the perfect google search) then posted here and headed to bed. Also, thanks for the `?` splainer. To be clear it has nothing to do with the actual character `?` I was trying to remove does it?

Comment: `?` was trick used in older Apache versions to strip off query string. In newer versions there is a specific flag `QSD` (query string discard) for this behavior.

Comment: Makes sense. Exactly what I'm dealing with. Just inherited a super old site to migrate.